# Why would disarming Dumbledore help Draco Malfoy duel him?

Tags: harry-potter, albus-dumbledore, draco-malfoy

1. Wandless magic exists. Draco knows this and can safely assume that Dumbledore is good at it.
2. It seems safe to assume that Dumbledore, even wandless, can best a 6th year Hogwarts student.
3. It follows that Draco, if he intends to duel Dumbledore, has no reason to disarm him.

What have I missed in Draco's reasoning?

Comment: Would you rather fight Rambo with or without his gun

Comment: @Turbo - That very much depends which film we're in; https://flowingdata.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/02/rambo-kill-chart1.jpg?w=640

Comment: 'Wandless magic exists' I mean not really. The instinctive magic of untrained young witches and wizards that bursts out of them unpredictably exists and there's very good reason to deduce that the animagus transformation is wandless and some debate about apparition too, but everything in the books makes it quite clear that the controlled and powerful magic of trained witches and wizards is chanelled through wands and being without one is crippling. You can get around unaided without the use of your legs, but depriving someone of the use of their legs is definitely a winning strategy in a fight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Malfoy did not have the luxury of making a rational assessment of the situation, and he was desperate to get a result at any cost. It is not clear whether Malfoy expected the disarming of Dumbledore to be sufficient to gain the upper hand. However, Malfoy was under enormous pressure from Voldemort to do everything possible to try and kill Dumbledore, no matter how hopeless or reckless the line of attack:

> ‘I haven’t got any options!’ said Malfoy, and he was suddenly as white as Dumbledore. ‘I’ve got to do it! He’ll kill me! He’ll kill my whole family!’

**Malfoy was more frightened of Voldemort than of Dumbledore, and would therefore be willing to risk defeat at the hands of the latter**. Indeed, it could be argued that Malfoy was acting rationally **in the expectation of being defeated by Dumbledore**, on the basis that:

- Dumbledore, with his reputation for mercy and clemency, would be more likely to capture rather than kill Malfoy;
- if Malfoy went back to Voldemort having failed in his mission to kill Dumbledore, Voldemort would probably kill Malfoy.

In that context, mounting a desperate bid to disarm Dumbledore is Malfoy's best option for staying alive one way or another, *either* **as a prisoner of Dumbledore** *or* (if successful in killing Dumbledore) **as a Death Eater who had succeeded in his mission**.

**As for why Malfoy succeeded in disarming and disabling Dumbledore**, it has to be said that Malfoy was quite lucky.

- Dumbledore was severely weakened by the potion he had drunk in the cave (in order to retrieve the locket) [of course, Malfoy would not have known about this].
- Dumbledore was multi-tasking, in that he was maintaining a spell to immobilise Harry (who was in the invisibility cloak) [again, Malfoy would not have known about this].
- It was due to this multi-tasking that Dumbledore was disarmed -- Malfoy cast the spell at the exact moment that Dumbledore was immobilising Harry, as the following passage demonstrates:

> The door burst open and somebody erupted thorough it and shouted: ‘*Expelliarmus!*’
>
> Harry's body became instantly rigid and immobile, [...]. He could not understand how it had happened -- *Expelliarmus* was not a Freezing Charm --
> [...] Dumbledore had wordlessly immobilised Harry, and the second he had taken to perform the spell had cost him the chance of defending himself.

- Wandless magic at a high level is more associated with African wizards/witches than European wizards/witches, and Dumbledore was a European wizard. Dumbledore, whilst he was certainly very accomplished at nonverbal spells (which are **not** the same thing), did not seem to engage in wandless magic to a great extent.
- The fact that Dumbledore was able to keep Harry immobilised despite being disarmed suggests that Dumbledore nonetheless did have capability in wandless magic. The immobilisation spell seems to have lifted only after Dumbledore's death:

> As they [Snape and company] vanished through the door Harry realised he could move again; what was now holding him paralysed against the wall was not [Dumbledore's] magic, but horror and shock.

- Dumbledore decided to engage with Malfoy through persuasion rather than duelling, a strategy predicated on the assumptions that:

  - Malfoy was not really a killer (an assumption that seems to have been correct); and that
  - Malfoy did not have allies on the scene (an assumption that proved to be disastrously wrong).
- Dumbledore had not anticipated that Malfoy would find a way to bring other Death Eaters into Hogwarts (despite Harry trying to alert Dumbledore to having seen Malfoy cry with delight in the Room of Requirement) **and** that these Death Eaters would overpower the patrols from the Order of the Phoenix, and therefore seems to have planned on the basis of persuading Malfoy to switch sides (although we learn in the subsequent book that Dumbledore had also anticipated that there would come a point where he would be cornered by Death Eaters and it would be expedient for Snape to kill him... so maybe, Dumbledore **did** suspect that Malfoy would succeed in bringing other Death Eaters, and decided to let it happen despite the enormous risk of collateral damage, just as he did nothing to prevent Malfoy from executing two murder attempts that missed Dumbledore but almost killed Katie Bell and Ron Weasley). Such a strategy may well have succeeded, had Malfoy not been joined by other Death Eaters.

Answer (score 4):

Draco was there to **kill** Dumbledore, not duel him.

That he led with *expelliarmus* rather than *avada kedavra* just shows that he wasn't a proper homicidal Death Eater after all.

Comment: Maybe he hasn't got the chops to do a killing curse. The last thing you want to do is cause Dumbledore a nosebleed

Comment: Oh no! Not the dreaded bumblebee nosebleed -

Answer (score 1):

1 I don’t see any mentioned in the books about Draco and wandless magic.

2a Wandless magic has never been mentioned in the canon as a controllable force. Wands are there to channel magical power and concentrate it. Making Dumbledore suddenly make wands useless 6.9 books in would’ve been a little bit of a kick in the ass for suspension of disbelief.

2b Dumbledore couldn’t even hold himself up because he had just drank Riddle’s potion. He probably would’ve struggled to perform wandless magic if he couldn’t even stand up straight.

3 Draco disabled Dumbledore because he did not want to duel him. Since wands are what make wizards dangerous, Draco got rid of Dumbledore’s. If it were a house elf or a goblin, he would’ve stunned them.

Comment: 1 is dubious - Draco has spent his entirely life in the Wizarding world. We can safely assume he has this knowledge. 2a is certainly false. Quirrel bound Harry wordlessly and wandlessly. 2b is irrelevant because Draco doesn't have that knowledge. 3's first sentence needs a lot more evidence.